# Combining rocks in triple town

Tags: triple-town

I accidentally found out that you can actually combine rocks (those things that resolve when you use a gem without a match). Two small rocks plus a gem resolves into a larger rock apparently, with what I remember as 1000 points.

If I keep on going on, will this eventually lead to something meaningful? a boulder? a diamond encrusted rock? maybe cake?

Those gems are precious, yo. Wouldn't want to squander them recklessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three rocks make a mountain. Three mountains make a silver chest. There is a nice evolution map [here](http://www.bbgsite.com/socialgames/content/triple-town/triple-town-strategy.shtml).

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them to make three boulders, then three mountains, and then you can use one to combine the two mountains and make a large chest. When you click the chest it randomly gives you items, moves, points, coins, and diamonds.